# BindingSource Refresh

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, business-objects, bindingsource

I have 2 classes i.e `CustomerOrder` and `Customer` class
has a reference to a collection of orders.
I use master detail `BindingSource`s.

My problem is when I use the lazy load pattern
for orders my detail `BindingSource` is not updated.

UI

```
BindingSource1.datasource = GetCustomers();
BindingSource2.DataMember = "Orders";
BindingSource2.datasource = BindingsSource1;
```

So in my `datagridView1` Click event

```
if (customer.orders != null)
{
  customer.Orders = LoadOrders();
}
```

I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Is this .NET? Sounds like WinForms but please Tag it as such.

Comment: Have you tried to reassign it?

Comment: you might wanna check out this link, http://sandbox.vbcity.com/blogs/vbfeeds/archive/2008/12/10/master-details-with-entity-framework-explicit-load.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Try reseting the binding:

```
BindingSource1.DataSource = GetCustomers();
BindingSource2.DataMember = "Orders";

BindingSource2.DataSource = BindingSource1;
BindingSource2.ResetBindings(true);
```

Comment: Unless the schema has changed, false can be passed as the parameter.